# DocuSign Fax Sheet Cover Re Generation through API?

Tags: docusignapi

Does anyone know of a way to regenerate the print and sign fax cover sheet through the API?  For example a client looses it or doesn't print correctly or we want to fax it on behalf of a client and they don't have a cover sheet.  Is there a way to regenerate it through the API?

Comment: able to find a way ?

Comment: No :(  and their rep told us that there is no current mechanism to do this.